# How to begin without a robot for now?

Tags: ros, tutorial, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm totally a newbie in ROS but i'm learning. I understand the concept of ROS.
My final purpose is to use ROS with a robot in order to try SLAM algorithms and Visual odometry algorithm. (i saw that there are some libraries to do that)

But now i don't know really how to begin. I don't have for now a robot (i have to wait a bit) but i have to begin to studies some algorithms.
Can you please give me some advises about how to start using some algorithms in order to manipulate a bit ROS? With a simulator ?(but i don't know how to proceed for now)

I try to find concrete examples on the internet but didn't find except the turtle_sim and the famous hello World,

Thank you,

EDIT:
And if i want to use a dataset like KITTI dataset, i don't need Gazebo right ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205340/how-to-begin-without-a-robot-for-now-?/) by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) can be used to simulate a robot and it can be used to test any algorithm you would like by connecting it to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1